# Send luggage to a pick-up point and retrieve after 2 weeks

Tags: luggage, japan, luggage-storage, tokyo, osaka

I would like to send a small suitcase ahead of me from Tokyo to Osaka. After I leave Tokyo myself, I will travel for 14 days before arriving in Osaka, so I can only pick up the luggage after that time. 
In the 14 days I will visit different places in Japan, where I don't need the suitcase.

Additionally, I will be staying in an Airbnb in Osaka where the host indicated they cannot receive packages, so I need to send it to some kind of pick-up point (e.g. post office, locker).

How do I do this?

I have tried asking at a luggage sending servicedesk (Sagawa at Skytree), they said they can send it to the Osaka airport (which is fine), but I have to pick it up the next day (which I cannot do).

[Japan-guide.com](https://www.japan-guide.com/e/e2278.html) says:

> Many companies allow deliveries to be delayed for a few days (typically up to one week)

However, I cannot find such an option indicated in English on one of the delivery service websites.

In my home country I can send parcels to a place, and they remain there for 30 days (after which they are returned). I was hoping to find a similar service in Japan.

Comment: There are luggage storage services in major airports and train stations that accept luggage deliveries and will hold them until you pick them up. Google something like "luggage storage Osaka station" and contact them directly.

Comment: Googling "luggage storage Osaka station" gives me storage info for when I'm present, but I'm looking for a point where I can send my luggage to and pick up later. I'm still looking for a solution and would appreciate if someone could recommend a service provider name or even just a way of indicating my goal in Japanese.

Comment: I don't know if this helps as you won't be staying at a hotel, but just FYI. http://www.global-yamato.com/en/hands-free-travel/  also  
http://www.global-yamato.com/en/hands-free-travel/scene03.html

Comment: Fedex could probably do it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Yamato](http://www.global-yamato.com/en/hands-free-travel/facilities/tokyo_station.html) was able to do it (found thanks to [@DXV](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/83479/dxv)).
They charged 1620 yen for sending it from Tokyo to an Osaka sales brach, delaying the delivery for 7 days.