# Shipping packages to the Netherlands months ahead?

Tags: netherlands, study, shipping, services, moving

I'm a student moving to the Netherlands this fall, currently in the US.  I need to move out of my current university in the next few weeks, and for the summer I'll be staying with a friend.  Is there some service that would allow me to send a package to the Netherlands ahead of time, have it stored there, and pick it up once I arrive in the country after a few months?

Comment: Rent a self-storage space, and send your packages there with an instruction to the courier to contact you to get the access code to store them. Your campus likely can recommend to you which service to pick.

Comment: I would go for a self storage where you are now and send the packages to arrive just after you.

Comment: Note that you are likely to face issues with customs. How much stuff are we talking about, and what kind?

Comment: How long will you be in the Netherlands?

Comment: Martheen, I'll see if I can arrange something like that! Willeke unfortunately, I will be spending the summer very far from where I currently am, so that makes it difficult to do so.  jcaron Mostly books.  Maybe some small applicanes as well like a speaker and a kettle, but it's probably more economical to find new ones when I arrive.  DavidRecallsMonica If things go well, 4,5 years.

Comment: When I moved from the UK to Sweden (so maybe not comparable) several ordinary international removals firms offered to collect my stuff and store it for free for up to a month before delivery - they would have stored it longer for a fee. Easier than self-storage imo. If you do go for self-storage, check the type of locks used - some companies here use physical locks so you have to be there to receive it.

Comment: most international moving companies should be able to arrange for a delayed delivery, by storing your stuff (for a fee, obv.) somewhere along the way.

Comment: I wonder if this question would be a better fit for the expats SE?

Comment: @Mousentrude while the current situation is more expatlike, the issue of sending stuff (luggage, parcels) to some place ahead of yourself is related to travel in my opinion. [I had a similar question for Japan a while ago](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/148347/2708)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some research and I found this company that provides a 'post bin / mail box' (postbus in Dutch) service. You will get a postal address to which you can send things.

https://www.allsafe.nl/en/storageneeds/mailbox-rental/

It's not super cheap though, if you want to do this as cheaply as possible I would try to connect with someone in the Netherlands (online or through your study) and simply ask if you could send your things over. It's a bit risky but I'd say in 99% of the cases things like this simply work out nicely with Dutch people. =)